# Python: How do I filter from a list of files in a directory using a datetime index?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I want to use python to iterate through a list of files in a directory that look like this, however I want to use a date range to filter out only the dates I want:

```
I:/directory
-file_2019-01-01.parquet
-file_2019-01-02.parquet
-file_2019-01-03.parquet
-file_2019-01-04.parquet
...
```

In R this is super easy with something like this:

```
seq.Date(as.Date(start), as.Date(stop), by  ="days") %>%
    pblapply(function(x) {
      read.fst(list.files(pattern = as.character(x)), as.data.table = T, columns = cols)...
```

But not sure how to do it in python. How would I add cross referencing to the function below to grab only the files between 2019-01-02 and 2019-01-04?

```
def pull_files(start, stop):
  
    #generate sequence of dates
    my_days = pd.date_range(start=start,end=stop)
    print(my_days)
    
    #identify path pattern
    HOW DO I BASICALLY CROSS REFERENCE my_days against os.listdir() so that I can return a list of only those three files that fit that range?


pull_files('2019-01-02','2019-01-04')
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way:

```
from pathlib import Path
from datetime import datetime

def pull_files(dir, start, stop):
    start_date_time = datetime.strptime(start, '%Y-%m-%d')
    stop_date_time = datetime.strptime(stop, '%Y-%m-%d')
    return [file
            for file in Path(dir).glob('*')
            if (start_date_time <= 
                datetime.strptime(file.stem.split('_')[-1], '%Y-%m-%d')
                <= stop_date_time)
            ]


pull_files('<your dir path here>', '2019-01-02', '2019-01-04')
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code is not optimized but it will work...

```
#identify path pattern

matches = []
files = os.listdir()

for file in files:
    for day in my_days:
        if day in file:
            matches.append(file)

return matches
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a `pandas` solution:

```
import pandas as pd
from glob import glob

files = glob('I:/directory/*.parquet') #get list of files

df = pd.DataFrame(files, columns=['filenames']) #load dataframe
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df['filenames'].str.split('_', 1).str[1].str.rsplit('.', 1).str[0]) #extract dates from filename and set datetime as index

df.loc['2019-01-02':'2019-01-04']['filenames'].to_list() #filter by date and convert to list
```